# WordPress missing user roles on local dev machine. Live site works fine

Tags: user-roles, permissions, user-meta

I have a live WordPress installation and a local one for development purposes. I just exported the live database, replaced all occurences of the live siteurl with the local one, and imported on my dev machine.

Problem is that on my dev machine all users have lost any permissions. When logging in I get:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /var/www/mysite/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php on line 1390
```

On a page template I dumped out the current userinfo with

```
global $current_user;
var_dump( get_currentuserinfo() );
```

This returns NULL on my dev machine and the correct userinfo on my live installation. I double checked the table prefixes, permissions, tried a clean WordPress installation, etc but had no luck. The confusing thing about this is, that I can query the userinfo perfectly fine with a custom sql query.

EDIT: Upon further inspection I found out that the global $wp_roles contains no user roles and capabilities. WordPress somehow can't retrieve this from the database...

EDIT 2: Sorry for the edits. But I found the problem. Inside the wp_options table there is a row "wp_user_roles". The value, an unserialized string did somehow include whitespaces which lead to errors when trying to unserialize the string. I replaced the database value with the live site's one and everything works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just exported the live database, replaced all occurences of the live
>   siteurl with the local one, and imported on my dev machine.

Finding/replacing with a text editor breaks serialized data; you must change values with MySQL queries in phpmyadmin:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.olddomain.com/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.olddomain.com/blog/','http://www.newdomain.com/');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.olddomain.com/blog/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://www.olddomain.com/blog/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/');
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone else has this issue:

I had two sites with a custom table prefix. This prefix is also used for some ***rows*** in the options table. When moving the options table from one site to another, I renamed the options table itself, but didn't know I had to rename some of the option names too, in particular the `wp_user_roles` option which was actually `prefix_user_roles`. There were several options in my `wp_options` (`prefix_options`) table with that prefix.

Wordpress automatically created the `prefix_user_roles` option when it did not recognize the `otherprefix_user_roles` option which locked me out.

Comment: Was very helpful! I too have the setup of a single database with multiple Wordpress installations segregated by different table prefixes. Started my first cloning with `phpMyAdmin` by selecting all the tables `wp_staging_*` then opened dropdown command menu →  With Selected →  Copy table with prefix → From `wp_staging_` to `wp_production_`. All worked fine, users could also login, but permissions were flaky. After updating prefixes in the `_options` and `_usermeta` tables too the user roles/permissions where fine again!

Comment: In depth description, including the SQL query which not only finds but also replaces the prefixes for you at: https://wp-staging.com/3-ways-to-change-the-wordpress-database-prefix-method-simplified/#Method_3_Rename_WordPress_Database_Prefix_using_Database_SQL_Query_with_PHPmyAdmin